# How to remove new line in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a problem to remove new line in vb .net.. ex:

> A
>  
>  B
>  C

i've try this code

> replace (string,chr(13),"*")

and the result is

> A*
>   *
>  B * 
>  C

i want to remove the new line after i replaced the chr(13) like this:

> A**B*C

i use this code for help me in text encryption with vigenere cipher
Help me please....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the Line Feed also, Chr(10), see this [link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html) for explanation.  In short a windows line ending consists of a Carriage Return and a Line Feed. and is represented in VB with the [`VbCrLf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf.aspx) constant.

Comment: @MarkHall Great Sir, no question since 2 years, 9 months?  :)

Comment: @GangOneStyle Nope most of my projects are in maintenance mode, and I haven't run into any show stoppers lately.

Answer (score 4):

The following string contains carriage returns. In VB they are declared as "vbCrLf", so you can remove them with

```
a = Replace(a, vbCrLf, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Example you have entered a string text like the one below:

```
Hi
I
Am
a .Net Developer...
```

You may do like this.

```
var c = txtWords.Text.Replace(@"\n","");
```

or

```
var c = txtWords.Text.Replace("\\n","");
```

Comment: Why C# answer to a vb.net question?